# X-Plane start in 3D mode (plugin C/C++)

Tags: c++

I want to start X-Plane 10 in 3D mode (3D cockpit) so I created this plugin, but it doesn't work. What's wrong? I've checked the X-Plane log and the plugin is loaded successfully.

```
/* This X-Plane plugin will enable 3D cockpit when X-Plane is started */

#pragma warning(disable: 4996) // Suppress warnings about unsafe operations in VS

#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "XPLMDataAccess.h" // Required to get access to X-Plane data references

#if IBM
// Required if plugin is running on Windows
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
#endif

/* This method is a part of the X-Plane plugin architecture. 
Will be executed when X-Plane loads the plugin. */
PLUGIN_API int XPluginStart(char* name, char* package, char* description) 
{
    // Describe our plugin to the X-Plane plugin system
    strcpy(name, "Enable3D");
    strcpy(package, "com.stackoverflow.enable3d");
    strcpy(description, "Enable 3D cockpit when X-Plane starts");

    // Contains the data reference file controlling the panel view
    XPLMDataRef panelRenderType = XPLMFindDataRef("sim/graphics/view/panel_render_type");

    // Set panel view to 3D cockpit
    XPLMSetDatai(panelRenderType, 2);

    // Initialization successful
    return 1;
}

/* This method is a part of the X-Plane plugin architecture.
Will be executed when X-Plane closes the plugin. */
PLUGIN_API void XPluginStop(void)
{
    // Do nothing
}

/* This method is a part of the X-Plane plugin architecture.
Will be executed when the user enables the plugin. */
PLUGIN_API int XPluginEnable(void)
{
    // Enabled successfully
    return 1;
}

/* This method is a part of the X-Plane plugin architecture.
Will be executed when the user disables the plugin. */
PLUGIN_API void XPluginDisable(void)
{
    // Do nothing
}

/* This method is a part of the X-Plane plugin architecture.
The method acts as a message handler. We don't have to do
anything here, but we must provide one. */
PLUGIN_API void XPluginReceiveMessage(XPLMPluginID caller, long message, void* param)
{
    // Do nothing
}
```

According to the documentation, the "sim/graphics/view/panel_render_type" data reference should be set to 1 for 2D-panel, 2 for 3D-panel and 3 for lit 3D-panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not everything in X-Plane is accessed via Datarefs.

You can tap into the key/joystick-button assignments system from the Plugin SDK.

Try this snippet:

```
XPLMCommandOnce( XPLMFindCommand( "sim/view/3d_cockpit_cmd_look" ) );
```

Combined with this "Deferred Initialisation" code:

http://www.xsquawkbox.net/xpsdk/mediawiki/DeferredInitialization#Example

When combined you should have a plugin that will enable 3D-cockpit mode.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the game, but the DataRefs sheet indicates that `sim/graphics/view/panel_render_type` is not writeable.

I don't have a good workaround at this point :/